# How to fix "The DTYPE <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> could not be promoted by <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>. No common DType

Tags: python, decision-tree, dtype

I am trying to use a decision tree to predict from a dataset, but the Decision Tree Classifier is causing the above error. The dataset contains object class data, int64, and datetime64 data. I have copied the full error below:

This is my first stack overflow question, so let me know if further info is needed.

```
\`\`y = cleaned_datacon \['days_on_market'\]` `x = cleaned_datacon.drop(columns=\['days_on_market'\])\`

`DTclf.fit(x,y)`

`--------------------------------------------------------------------------- `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)\`\`
`~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12312\3583540280.py in <module>`
`----> 1 DTclf.fit(x,y)`

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\tree_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input)
887         """
888
\--\> 889         super().fit(
890             X,
891             y,

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\tree_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input)
184             check_X_params = dict(dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
185             check_y_params = dict(ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
\--\> 186             X, y = self.\_validate_data(
187                 X, y, validate_separately=(check_X_params, check_y_params)
188             )

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\base.py in \_validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, \*\*check_params)
577                 if "estimator" not in check_X_params:
578                     check_X_params = {\*\*default_check_params, \*\*check_X_params}
\--\> 579                 X = check_array(X, input_name="X", \*\*check_X_params)
580                 if "estimator" not in check_y_params:
581                     check_y_params = {\*\*default_check_params, \*\*check_y_params}

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\utils\\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
776         )
777         if all(isinstance(dtype_iter, np.dtype) for dtype_iter in dtypes_orig):
\--\> 778             dtype_orig = np.result_type(\*dtypes_orig)
779
780     elif hasattr(array, "iloc") and hasattr(array, "dtype"):

\<__array_function__ internals\> in result_type(\*args, \*\*kwargs)

TypeError: The DType \<class 'numpy.dtype\[datetime64\]'\> could not be promoted by \<class 'numpy.dtype\[float64\]'\>. This means that no common DType exists for the given inputs. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`. The full list of DTypes is: (\<class 'numpy.dtype\[int64\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[int64\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[int64\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[float64\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[datetime64\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[datetime64\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[int64\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[float64\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[float64\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[int64\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[float64\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[int32\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[int32\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[int32\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[int32\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[int32\]'\>, \<class 'numpy.dtype\[int32\]'\>)\`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the `datetime64` columns to `float64` type.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71259141) may help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34555770)

Comment: That doesn't help when we're trying to e.g. do a plot or histogram of the resulting data, since all we end up with is a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest breaking down the datetime64 column into separate date/time features, ie. month/hour/weekday etc., and feed those into the model instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).